# getsymphony.com - about what is this website?

Tags: symfony

I'm little confused about **http://getsymphony.com** and **http://symfony.com/** websites. I'm looking for place where I can start learning Symfony framework and I have no idea if **http://getsymphony.com** site have any reference to **[Symfony framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/)** or this is only tricky name for unknown CMS. Can someone explain me this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PHP Symfony Framework is named "Symfony", with a `f`, not `ph`. Its documentation is available at [symfony.com](http://symfony.com).

[Symphony](http://getsymphony.com) with `ph` seems to be a PHP CMS, not related to the framework.